# Where should I put this custom data?

Tags: customization, database

My client needs to store food nutrient data in his site's database. I have food name, calories, protein, fat, carb, fiber and other data to store for many food items.

I'm a developer but new to WP. Where is the best place to store this information? A custom table, custom post, regular...

Thanks!

Comment: I think your should use custom post type for this.

Comment: You can use custom post type. For extra fields, use post meta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing that each food item is treated as a post (perhaps even a custom post type), and the parameters (name/calories/etc.) are attributes of this post, you would do well to treat them as [post meta fields](http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields).

Various means exist to grant end-users the ability to maintain custom fields; my preferred option is [Developer's Custom Fields](https://wordpress.org/plugins/developers-custom-fields/), but other solutions exist.  Regardless of the method used, the assumption is that for a given post certain meta fields have been populated and must be queried at runtime.

Within a loop (in particular, after invoking `the_post()`), and for a particular custom field (for illustration I will use "calories"), you would retrieve the value using [`get_post_meta()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) as shown below:

```
echo "Calories: " . get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), "calories", true);
```

Some assumptions are made here (that you're in a page/post loop, the data you are requesting has already been entered, and the name of your custom field is "calories").